# Is there any way for QLocale::formattedDataSize function to return the translation quantified units?

Tags: qt, qlocale

QLocale::formattedDataSize always return English quantified units.

Comment: Is there any way for formattedDataSize function to return the translation quantified units?

Comment: What do you mean by "English quantified units"? Do you need a translation for "KB", "MB" and so on? Or is the number format wrong? Could you give an example of what you want and what you get?

Comment: Yes, I want translation KB", "MB" in language from QLocation::system.

Comment: @deMax KB, MB are units that are based on a standard and should not be translated as they are universal, maybe this is wrong, could you point me example of translations?

Comment: @eyllanesc, there are languages, like Russian for example, where [the units are translated](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%91%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82), because of own standards.

Comment: @scopchanov Exactly, it's another standard, you have to check if Qt supports several standards and change it, not the locale.

Comment: @deMax, please, post an example, in which the units are not translated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The units are clearly translated, as seen from the source code of [qlocale_data_p.h](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qlocale_data_p.h.html#byte_unit_data).

This private header defines an array named `byte_unit_data` with the following content as characters:

> byteskB;MB;GB;TB;PB;EBKiB;MiB;GiB;TiB;PiB;EiBbytegrepebajtባይትኪባ;ሜጋባይት;ጊባ;ቴራባይት;PB;EBبايتكيلوبايت;ميغابايت;غيغابايت;تيرابايت;PB;EBբայթերկԲ;ՄԲ;ԳԲ;ՏԲ;PB;EBবাইটকিঃ
>   বাঃ;মেঃ বাঃ;গিঃ বাঃ;টেঃ
>   বাঃ;PB;EBbaytbyte-akoktedoùko;Mo;Go;To;Po;EoKio;Mio;Gio;Tio;Pio;Eioбайтовеဘိုက်байтыКБ;МБ;ГБ;ТБ;PB;EBបៃ字节千字节;兆字节;吉字节;太字节;PB;EB位元組bajtovibajtybaididbýtKB;MB;GB;TB;PB;EBtavutkt;Mt;Gt;Tt;Pt;EtKit;Mit;Git;Tit;Pit;Eitoctetsbaidhtბაიტიკბაიტი;მბაიტი;გბაიტი;ტბაიტი;PB;EBBytesબાઇટבייטबाइटbájtbætibeartaバイトಬೈಟ್‌ಗಳುಕಿ.ಬೈ.;ಮೆ.ಬೈ.;ಗಿ.ಬೈ.;ಟೆ.ಬೈ.;PB;EBбайткБ;MБ;ГБ;TБ;PБ;EБKiБ;MiБ;GiБ;TiБ;PiБ;EiБкБ;МБ;ГБ;ТБ;PB;EB바이트baitibaitaiбајтиbaitബൈറ്റ്കി.ബി.;മെ.ബൈ.;ജി.ബൈ.;ടിബി;PB;EBବାଇଟ୍بایتکیلوبایت;مگابایت;گیگابایت;ترابایت;PB;EBਬਾਇਟbyțiбајтовиبائيٽزڪلو
>   بائيٽز;ميگا بائيٽز;گيگا بائيٽز;ٽيرا بائيٽز;PB;EBබයිට්කිබ {0};මෙබ
>   {0};ගිබ {0};ටෙබ {0};PB;EBkilobaiti {0};MB {0};GB {0};terabaiti
>   {0};PB;EBபைட்கள்బైట్‌లుకేబీ;ఎమ్‌బి;జీబీ;టీబీ;PB;EBไบต์paitikB ʻe
>   {0};MB ʻe {0};GB ʻe {0};TB ʻe {0};PB ʻe {0};EB ʻe {0}KiB ʻe {0};MiB ʻe
>   {
>
> ...

So you have to use the correct locale (from the location in your user profile I assume it is *Russian*) and format `QLocale::DataSizeTraditionalFormat` like this:

```
QLocale l(QLocale::Russian, QLocale::Russia);

l.formattedDataSize(154, 2, QLocale::DataSizeTraditionalFormat);        // "154 байты"
l.formattedDataSize(19324, 2, QLocale::DataSizeTraditionalFormat);      // "18,87 кБ"
l.formattedDataSize(125839324, 2, QLocale::DataSizeTraditionalFormat);  // "120,01 МБ"
```

Comment: I ran my test project and it worked fine. Probably before did not correctly change the locale, this worked - 
LANGUAGE=ru_RU.utf8 ; LANG=ru_RU.utf8 ; LC_ALL=ru_RU.utf8

Comment: Thanks, I understood the problem is not in the code.